# gdk_window_set_composited called but compositing is not supported

Tags: gtk3

Inside the "tests" folder of gtk+-3.2.3 there's a script called "testgtk".
When you run the script you get a UI with 56 buttons to launch other demo's. 
The demo "alpha windows" works but "composited window" only gives a button on a red window with the warning:

> Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_composited called but compositing is
>   not supported

I'm on Ubuntu Natty, gtk+-3.2.3

Comment: Have you got a window manager running that supports compositing? Ex. compiz, unity3d?

Comment: I'm running full Ubuntu not classic or classic-no-effects. I have compiz version 1:0.9.4+bzr20110415-0ubuntu2.

I'm running proprietary graphics drivers. The results of lspci -nn | grep VGA are: 01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ATI Technologies Inc RS780M/RS780MN [Radeon HD 3200 Graphics] [1002:9612]

In gconf-editor under: apps->metacity->general I have "compositing_manager" checked.

When I run the alpha demo it says: "Screen supports alpha" and "composited"